# How to Integrate Kie-workbench with springboot?

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I am having Kie workbench and I am having seperate springboot application. Now i want to use certain rules created in that workbench from my local spring boot application....

What are the steps to be followed to interact with KIE Workbench and what are the configurations to be made on both sides(KIE WORKBENCH & Springboot application)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have kie-server.war installed along with workbench?

If yes, then you can deploy your project into kie-server and use REST API or java client to fire rules from your application. Please refer documentation [Kie-server installation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.25.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_ch.kie.server) to understand more about using kie-server to deploy projects and configurations.

Comment: yes, Kie-server.war was placed in the deployment folder in wildfly server.But still i have the same issue,

Comment: Did you deploy the project created in business-central to the kie-server?

Comment: yes,I deployed.i am getting that message in rule when i tried from post man.But from SpringBoot It can't.